# Bug JDK-8191002 unclear if programming error or JRE error

Tags: java, garbage-collection, thread-safety, finalize

Regarding the issue described in JDK-8191002, also discussed in [Java Cipher - PBE thread-safety issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46971788/java-cipher-pbe-thread-safety-issue#) : 
it is unclear to me if the usage of Arrays.fill() in the finalize() method is correct or if it is a bug. Some answers suggest that a reachabilityFence should be used, but does this mean that it was a bug, or does this mean that the reachabilityFence is a workaround around a bug in the VM? 
Anybody who can clarify/comment?

Copied from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6: "Furthermore, none of the pre-finalization reads of fields of that object may see writes that occur after finalization of that object is initiated."
This suggests that the code for NewlyAllocatedArrayFilledByOtherInstanceFinalizer in JDK-8191002 is correct, and that the failure is due to JVM. Or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, this is a bug in the Java code, not a bug in the JVM.

This code pattern has been abstracted in [JDK-8191002](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8191002) with

```
static class ArrayHolder 
{ 
    private byte[] _bytes; 

    ArrayHolder(final byte[] bytes) { _bytes = bytes.clone(); } 

    byte[] getBytes() { return _bytes.clone(); } 

    @Override 
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable 
    { 
        if (_bytes != null) 
        { 
            Arrays.fill(_bytes, (byte) 'z'); 
            _bytes = null; 
        } 
        super.finalize(); 
    } 
}
```

where `getBytes()` may indeed spuriously return `z` filled arrays instead of an array reflecting the original contents (in theory, it could even return partially filled arrays).

The “reading of a field” is the reading of the array *reference*. The cloning of the array (or any processing of the array) happens *afterwards*, hence, doesn’t prevent the owner of the field from being garbage collected.

Since there is no action that enforces inter-thread memory visibility, this “reading of a field” is not even required to actually happen, the thread may reuse a previously read value (still talking of the value of the *reference* here), allowing an even earlier collection of the object. This still obeys the requirement of not perceiving writes to the field made by the finalizer, if the finalizer changed the reference.

As said, this doesn’t say anything about the array’s contents, as it isn’t the array that has been garbage collected. The array and the object containing a reference to the array are two entirely different objects.

Placing a reachability fence on holder after the cloning of the array creates a new dependency that wasn’t there in that the array holder can’t get collected before the cloning of the array has been completed.

```
byte[] getBytes() { 
    byte[] result = _bytes.clone(); 
    Reference.reachabilityFence(this); 
    return result; 
}
```

Without it, the last access to the object is *before* the invocation of `clone()`, but as said, that access might get optimized away by reusing a previously read reference. As stated by JLS §12.6.1.:

> Optimizing transformations of a program can be designed that reduce the number of objects that are reachable to be less than those which would naively be considered reachable.

Comment: Thanks, clear explanation. Imho JDK-8191002 should have been rejected (instead of "duplicate"), but OK, that's another discussion.